# using cmake to link object files into lib.xxxx.a file

Tags: object, cmake

I've got a list of object files that I want to package in a library.
How do I do this? I thought I could use ADD_LIBRARY

Answer (score 3):

`add_library` is the correct answer. To make a static library, you want to do something like this:

```
add_library(foo STATIC foo.c bar.c baz.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries are becoming a bit obsolete, but "ar" is the command you are looking for.