# Linking multiple static .lib files into one monolithic .lib file using VS2008 SP1 using CMake 2.8.x

Tags: linker, cmake, static-libraries

Related to [using cmake to link object files into lib.xxxx.a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3974415/257924), but not quite the same thing, I have built several static libraries on Windows using CMake 2.8.x using VS2008 SP1. Is there a way via CMake alone to relink all of the .obj files inside all of those existing static libraries into one larger monolithic library, preferably via the `add_library` CMake function, or other similar construct?

I think the answer is "no", and so I have thought about rolling my own via a custom command via the usual `add_custom_command` + `add_custom_target` approach, that simply constructs the library manually, by supplying all of the other libraries .obj files when calling `LINK.EXE`. But I see some problems with that approach:

1. I could not find a CMake variable that indicates the fully-qualified path to the `LINK.EXE` executable. I would then have to somehow derive the path to `LINK.EXE` using a fragile heuristic: It is fragile in the sense that different Visual Studio versions may locate the `LINK.EXE` file in different directories, and I'm needing this to work for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows compiler conditions, and be resilient against upgrades between VS2008 and future compiler revisions.
2. I would have to find a way to find all of the .obj files of the other static libraries, *at build time* versus *at CMake time*, since at CMake time the .obj files of course do not (always) exist. For reasons of build performance, I desire not to resort to extracting the .obj files from the .lib files for the sake of adding them to the `LINK.EXE` command line, so a `FILE(GLOB...)` construct would be my best second alternative in this case.
3. It may be possible to simply call `LINK.EXE` via: `LINK.EXE /OUT:monolithic.lib lib1.lib lib2.lib ...`, but maybe not all .obj's will be included (EDIT: I have confirmed that `LINK.EXE` omits some .obj files from `lib1.lib lib2.lib ...` without any diagnostic messages explaining why, so this approach is a non-starter); the online docs for `LINK.EXE` are unclear as to that point. Anyone have any experience with using `LINK.EXE` in that manner?

Thanks,

Brent

P.S., I know how to create a DLL using CMake, but I specifically do not want to resort to building a DLL at this point in time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a static library "merged" with a dummy source file, and add libs to be merged to the STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS, so they will be additional input to lib.exe.

This would be something like:

ADD_LIBRARY(merged STATIC dummy.c)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(merged PROPERTIES
  STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "full\path\to\lib1.lib full\path\to\lib2.lib")

This approach is used inside MySQL, there is a more general macro here to merge static libraries that works crosss-platform. It can be found here http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg28670/libutils.cmake

Comment: MERGE_STATIC_LIBS macro defined in the http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg28670/libutils.cmake link is very close to what I would have implemented. A warning: That link points to a file that is mysql-specific, so it would have to be generalized for it to be workable in practice.

Comment: The above libutils.cmake indeed does not work standalone,as it references configurable merge_archives_unix.cmake.in This file is available from http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg28670/merge_archives_unix.cmake.in