# "Linking" my static lib with a third-party static lib

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm writing a CMake script that makes a static library `MyLib`. I'd like to [concatenate it with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821916/how-to-merge-two-ar-static-libraries-into-one) a 3rd party static library `AnotherLib`. I try to accomplish this as follows:

1. "Deconstruct" `AnotherLib` to object files by invoking `ar` as a part of `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND`.
2. Prepare an intermediate `MyLibObj` using `ADD_LIBRARY(MyLibObj OBJECT ${MYLIB_SOURCES})`
3. Make the final `MyLib` using (1) and (2) -- here is the problem. How to do this? Is it possible to make `CMake` treat the object files made in (1) as `OBJECT` library?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/blob/master/cmake/merge_archives_unix.cmake.in) `CMake` script merges several static libraries - but in a straightforward way, without the new `OBJECT` feature. It's a part of `MERGE_STATIC_LIBS` macro referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415460/linking-multiple-static-lib-files-into-one-monolithic-lib-file-using-vs2008-sp?rq=1).