# How can I remove the "the Location property may not be read from target" error in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am now trying run a CMake script in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991808/cmake-how-to-get-target-file-location). With this script, CMake will print all the properties of a target. However, when it tries to retrieve the `LOCATION` property of the target, the following error is observed:

```
The LOCATION property may not be read from target "abc".  Use the target
  name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator expression
  $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.
```

Then I tried to print the property with `message($<TARGET_FILE:abc>)`, but it does not work either. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are refering to [this](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/390) post, recommended by @m.s. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183975/how-to-print-all-the-properties-of-a-target-in-cmake) (your link above refers to [CMAKE How to get Target File Location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991808/cmake-how-to-get-target-file-location)). The error you get comes from [policy CMP0026](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/policy/CMP0026.html). Either call `cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 OLD)` or - better - remove the `LOCATION` properties from the list of properties to be printed.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Florian's comment, reading the `LOCATION` property of a target is an **error** by default in today's CMake versions. The documentation for [CMake Policy 0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0026.html) clearly describes *why* this is the case:

> CMake 2.8.12 and lower allowed reading the `LOCATION` target property (and configuration-specific variants) to determine the eventual location of build targets. This relies on the assumption that all necessary information is available at configure-time to determine the final location and filename of the target. However, this property is not fully determined until later at generate-time.

After reading the `LOCATION` property, it can later be changed using generator expressions. CMake allows you to disable this policy, by setting it to the `OLD` behavior [explicitly](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html#setting-policies-explicitly):

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 OLD)
```

Just take the result with a grain of salt, as it may change!

If you're going to change the policy (instead of simply removing `LOCATION` from the list of properties), it is best to use `OLD` CMake policies in isolation. When we're done using the `OLD` behavior, we can `POP` the old policy off the CMake policy [stack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html#cmake-policy-stack) to resume using the `NEW` behavior. Here's the [example](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-target-properties/) you referred to, modified to demonstrate usage of the policy change:

```
function(echo_target tgt)
    if(NOT TARGET ${tgt})
        message("There is no target named '${tgt}'")
        return()
    endif()

    set(props
        DEBUG_OUTPUT_NAME
        DEBUG_POSTFIX
        RELEASE_OUTPUT_NAME
        ...
        LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC
        LOCATION
        LOCATION_DEBUG
        ...
        WIN32_EXECUTABLE
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_WHATEVER
    )
    message(STATUS "======================== ${tgt} ========================")

    # Push the current (NEW) CMake policy onto the stack, and apply the OLD policy.
    cmake_policy(PUSH)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 OLD)

    foreach(p ${props})
        # v for value, d for defined, s for set
        get_property(v TARGET ${tgt} PROPERTY ${p})
        get_property(d TARGET ${tgt} PROPERTY ${p} DEFINED)
        get_property(s TARGET ${tgt} PROPERTY ${p} SET)
        # only produce output for values that are set
        if(s)
            message(STATUS "tgt='${tgt}' p='${p}'")
            message(STATUS "  value='${v}'")
            message(STATUS "  defined='${d}'")
            message(STATUS "  set='${s}'")
            message(STATUS "")
        endif()
    endforeach()

    # Pop the previous policy from the stack to re-apply the NEW behavior.
    cmake_policy(POP)

    message(STATUS "")
endfunction()
```