# CMake properties and expanding generator expressions

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to combine several static libraries with CMake and I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415460/linking-multiple-static-lib-files-into-one-monolithic-lib-file-using-vs2008-sp/4736442#4736442) that suggests doing the following:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(merged PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "full\path\to\lib1.lib full\path\to\lib2.lib")
```

The libraries I want to combine are the output of other targets and when I want to refer to the output of a target I usually use generator expression such as $< TARGET_FILE:MyLib>. However in this context it does not work because the generator expression does not get expanded before being passed to the linker and it complains that $< TARGET_FILE:MyLib> cannot be found.

This does not work:

```
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS $<TARGET_FILE:MyLib>)
```

I guess I am meant to set the property to the path of the library:

```
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS ${CURRENT_BIN_DIR}/MyLib.lib})
```

Generating this path manually can be tedious (I have many targets) and I was wondering if, given a target, there was a better way to get that path automatically.

For example (I am making up the syntax here):

```
set_target_properties(merged PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS EXPAND_PATH($<TARGET_FILE:MyLib>))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that [generator expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) would have been the right choice - especially in multi-configuration environments - but if a certain command or property does not support them, you can't trick them into working.

But there are alternatives:

**Setting `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` Property**

You could slightly change your "I guess I am meant to" strategy and place your library outputs you want to merge into a path of your own choosing. The following example is for a multi-configuration environment like Visual Studio:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC bar.cc)
set_target_properties(lib1 PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libs")

file(WRITE dummy.cc "")
add_library(merged STATIC dummy.cc) 
add_dependencies(merged lib1)

set_target_properties(
    merged PROPERTIES 
        STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libs/Debug/lib1.lib"
        STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libs/Release/lib1.lib"
)
```

**Using `OBJECT` Libraries**

Or you can work with [OBJECT libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) as intermediate grouping targets to prevent having to trick CMake into building your `merged` library:

```
add_library(lib1 OBJECT bar.cc)
add_library(lib2 OBJECT foo.cc)
add_library(merged $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib1> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lib2>)
```

I personally prefer the later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started implementing something similar to your first solution but the second alternative looks much cleaner. I'll check how it would work in my project.