# CMake Wildcard for TARGET_OBJECTS

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following directory structure

```
-  CMakeLists.txt
-  include
    -  a.hh
-  lib
    -  CMakeLists.txt
    -  a.cc
-  src
    -  CMakeLists.txt
    -  main.cc
-  test
    -  CMakeLists.txt
    -  test.cc
```

I am using CMake for compiling test.cc using the command

```
add_executable(test test.cc $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)
```

and the object file `A.o` is compiled as

```
add_library(A OBJECT A.cc)
```

but the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>` command becomes ugly very quickly. Is there any way to tell CMake to include all `.o` files in the lib folder for linking everything?

Comment: I would say there is nothing like wildcards that isn't at least as long as the command you are currently using (and which would still be cross-platform compatible). Can you elaborate a little on what you mean with "getting ugly"? There is maybe a solution that hides if you are using object libraries in a macro, but I'm not sure if this is the direction you want to go.

Comment: By getting ugly, I mean, the list of linked libraries grows long enough to be untrackable and hence error prone. Object A, Object B and so on, and may be you forgot C in list of 5 and you didn't notice.

Comment: You may collect all references to your static libraries in  list variable, and use it for create executable: `set(my_source_libs)`, `list(APPEND my_source_libs $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)`, `list(APPEND my_source_libs $<TARGET_OBJECTS:B>)`, ...,`add_executable(test test.cc ${my_libs})`. There are many other *programming* ways to achive similar effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

There is no build-in syntax like wildcards to simplify your `add_executable(test test.cc $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A>)` command.

Actually - to improve the convenience of handling object libraries in my current project - I've gone all the way of modifying my CMake version's source code to extend the `target_link_libraries()` to accept object libraries the same way it does static or shared libraries.

But there are other ways that may help you handling large amounts of object libraries:

1. You could group object libraries into intermediate static libraries (but that somehow negates the effect of using object libraries):

   ```
   add_library(A OBJECT a.cc)
   add_library(B OBJECT b.cc)
   add_library(AB $<TARGET_OBJECTS:A> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:B>)
   ```
2. You could "extend" the functionality of `add_executable()` e.g. with a function like:

   ```
   function(my_add_executable _target)
       foreach(_source IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
           if (NOT TARGET "${_source}")
               list(APPEND _source_list "${_source}")
           else()
               get_target_property(_type "${_source}" TYPE)
               if (_type STREQUAL "OBJECT_LIBRARY")
                   list(APPEND _source_list "$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${_source}>")
               else()
                   message(SEND_ERROR "my_add_executable: '${_source}' given as parameter is not a object-library target.")
               endif()
           endif()
       endforeach()
       add_executable(${_target} ${_source_list})
   endfunction(my_add_executable)
   ```

   Then you could mix your source files with names of object libraries. To prevent to much confusion I would recommend using more descriptive object library names (e.g. by adding a "Objs" suffix):

   ```
   add_library(AObjs OBJECT a.cc)
   ...
   my_add_executable(testA test.cc AObjs)
   ```

**References**

- [CMake properties and expanding generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623207/cmake-properties-and-expanding-generator-expressions)

Comment: do you have any plans to upstream your code to cmake for your modified `target_link_libraries`, that would be immensely useful.

Comment: second option of appening target_objects to a list does not seem to work. Atleast for 3.17. Is there a better way ? By the way, I was creating a library rather than an executable.